# Get properties with reflection

Tags: c#, reflection

Here is a method in my Xaml.cs:

```
void itemListView_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (this.UsingLogicalPageNavigation())
            {
                this.navigationHelper.GoBackCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
            }

            // Here is the object which properties i am trying to get:
            var mySelectedItem = e.AddedItems[0];

            //Here I would like to acess the properties

        }
```

Im trying to use reflection to get the propertes from mySelected Item.
Been trying things like:

```
PropertyInfo property = GetType().GetProperty(propertyName) <--Cant resolve GetProperty()
```

and

```
object value = propertyInfo.GetValue(mySelectedItem);<--Cant resolve PropertyInfo
```

Is it not possibe to use refelctionin this scenario?

Comment: Doesn't `mySelectedItem.MyProperty` work?

Comment: sorry mate i m not able to understand what ur trying to convey but i can give u working reflection example if u need

Comment: MyselectedItem contains an object that gets passed into this method with the parameter e. I would like to get a hold of the values from two of its properties in order to assign them to another var.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but your question isn't clear what is the probelm. What happens? What is the exact compiler or runtime exception if any? Also why do you need to use reflection anyway?

Comment: @BenjaminDiele
No, when mySelectedItem. allows me the following four possibilities:
Equals, GetHashCode,GetType and ToString

Comment: Are you sure you want reflection and not just a cast?

Comment: @DirkWrangler Then you should cast your object like Matthew says.

Comment: Im not sure which is the best way for me to get a hold of the properties in MySelectedItem. Im open to any suggestions.

Comment: @DirkWrangler You cast it as follows: `MyObject myCastedObject = (MyObject)mySelectedItem`. I'm surprised you know of reflection but not casting..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need reflection for what you want.

You can access the properties of your objects when you cast them to the right object.

```
void itemListView_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.UsingLogicalPageNavigation())
        {
            this.navigationHelper.GoBackCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
        }
        var mySelectedItem = e.AddedItems[0];

        MyObject myObject = (MyObject)mySelectedItem;

        // Now you can access your property as follows: myObject.MyProperty;

    }
```

Comment: This was exactly what i needed!
And it only took 4 downvotes!

Comment: @DirkWrangler I think it's because you didn't pose a very good question. Next time add the bigger picture as well :)